# Correct way to post file to Laravel server using Angular 8

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5

I am trying to post an array of files along with some other data to a laravel server using angular. The file information gets set on the angular side and File object is there when the data is posted. However if I just return the request, the File data has been removed and I get a empty array. The rest of my data is fine though.

My service code:

```
storeChecklistAnswers(checklistAnswers: ChecklistAnswersModel) {
        return this.http
            .post<any>(
                `${environment.apiUrl}/checklist/answers/store`,
                checklistAnswers,
                {
                    reportProgress: true,
                    headers: new HttpHeaders().append(
                        'enctype',
                        'multipart/form-data'
                    )
                }
            )
            .pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    let errors;
                    if (error.error.errors) {
                        errors = {
                            message: error.message,
                            errors: Object.values(error.error.errors)
                        };
                    } else if (error.error.message) {
                        errors = {
                            message: error.error.message
                        };
                    } else {
                        errors = {
                            message:
                                'An unknown error has occured. Please refresh the application'
                        };
                    }
                    return throwError(errors);
                }),
                tap(resultData => {
                    return resultData;
                })
            );
    }
```

In my controller

```
return response()->json([
            'data' => $request->all()
        ]);
```

The data before it is posted:

```
images: Array(1)
0:
file: File
name: "292588.jpg"
lastModified: 1568349822014
lastModifiedDate: Fri Sep 13 2019 06:43:42 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 282431
type: "image/jpeg"
__proto__: File
```

The actual response

```
images: Array(1)
0:
file: []
```

I have tried to remove the headers as suggested in some SO answers, but I get the same result
I have also checked file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size in php.ini.

I am running out of ideas. Please could someone point me in the right direction. I am not sure why I cant post the file?

Comment: did you pass csrf token from angular code? you need to pass a csrf token if you are using post method for your route

Comment: mmh... for files to work or any post request? I have quite a few post request that are working fine without this

Comment: to make any post request to server you need to pass csrf token from laravel Since 5.2.27 , exceptional cases like, you are using a custom route file and not include the web middleware or you are using api route. which version of laravel 5 you are using?

Comment: hey, Laravel is only an API in my case. Surely Angular cant generate a csrf token? Like I mentioned all my other post request from angular to api are working fine without this

Comment: if you are using `api` route, then you don't need, I thought you are using web routes. just for your knowledge you have to generate csrf token and store it on header meta data, later you can access it through javascript..

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Also as @Akram Wahid suggested make sure you have included csrf token.

And regarding file post see below code sample.

**Your angular template**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h3>Choose File</h3>
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="image"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Your angular component file**

```
export class AppComponent {

    fileData = null;
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
        this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    }

    onSubmit() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.fileData);
        this.http.post('url/to/your/api', formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'  
        })
        .subscribe(events => {
            if(events.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                console.log('Upload progress: ', Math.round(events.loaded / events.total * 100) + '%');
            } else if(events.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                console.log(events);
            }
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but this does not change anything. Like I mentioned to @Akrim I am posting to API routes not web routes